# Dev dependencies not getting installed in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I am trying to create a container for react and express and run both the containers on same network using docker compose.

Below is my dockerfile for frontend:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Below is my dockerfile for backend

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN NODE_ENV=development npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","run","server"]
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build: 
      context: './frontend'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    container_name: react_cont
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    networks:
    - mern
    volumes:
    - ./frontend:/app
    depends_on:
    - server
  server:
    build:
      context: './backend'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    container_name: express_cont
    networks:
    - mern
    volumes:
    - ./backend:/app
networks:
  mern:
```

react container is getting is created and running successfully but the express container is not getting created with an error

```
sh: nodemon: not found
```

I had installed nodemon as my dev dependency.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: I had installed nodemon globally in my machine because of which i was able to run ```nodemon server.js ``` in scripts, without even installing it for my current project. I mistakenly thought i have installed nodemon for my current project. Thank you sir.

Comment: Your Compose `volumes:` blocks are hiding everything that your Dockerfile does.  Is it possible that the `RUN npm install` line is installing the tool, but then the `volumes:` mount is hiding that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own Question.

I had installed nodemon globally in my machine but forgot to install it as a dependency for my current project.

Since nodemon was installed globally in my machine i was not getting any errors while i was trying to run my server.js using nodemon. `nodemon server.js` in scripts did not throw any error while i was in developing my project locally prior moving it to docker container.

But since neither my package.json had nodemon as my dependency and i had not installed it separately in my container nodemon did not get installed and it gave me error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install `nodemon` package globally in your Docker:

```
RUN NODE_ENV=development npm install && npm --global install nodemon
```

Comment: He could also install nodemon as a dev dependency in the project and avoid this extra command. Doing `npm i --save-dev nodemon` in the project would work for anyone developing for/building that project, including docker.

Comment: You right of course, I was under the impression that package is already defined under `devDependencies` in package.json file...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete `node_modules` folder in your source code and add flag `--production=false` explicitly to the `npm install` command. I think it's caching problem.